# SDC or LDC for specific cymbals?

Tags: recording, microphones, mixing

Not exactly your typical SDC vs LDC question here.

I have 2 condenser mics, a Samson C01 Pencil SDC and a PreSonus LDC.

Say I have the rest of a drum kit miked up properly, but also wanted to record the Hats and the Ride as well. Which type of condenser would you use for which cymbal?

I'm leaning towards using the SDC on the Hats and the LDC on the Ride, because with the Ride track I would be happier with getting a bit more of the sound from the whole kit, where as the Hats track I would want as isolated as I can get it.

What do you guys think and why?

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use the one that either sounds best to me or fits the mix I'm going for, regardless of diaghram size. In this case I'd put the one that is less clear on the hats since I don't like a lot of nuance there, whereas on the ride I like to hear all of what's going on.